# How can I derive an approximate equation for the forward voltage drop of a particular component?

Tags: diodes

I have a situation where I have ADC value for a battery voltage and I am trying to re-create and display the actual battery voltage. Fairly straight forward situation but there is a diode drop in there that complicates things. The ADC values are taken after the diode and I am trying to display the actual battery voltage. I know the current through the diode at the time of the reading so my plan was to calculate Vf and add it to the reading.

The specific diode I am using is [SSA34-E3/61T](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88883/88883.pdf). It has a graph of the forward voltage as a function of current. My initial thought was to take a few values from this graph, drop it into excel, fit a logarithmic trendline to it and use the equation for that line to calculate the offset as a function of current. However, that trendline doesn't match very well as current surpasses 500mA or so. Any thoughts as to how I might calculate this with some accuracy?

Comment: could you add in a copy of what you have already graphed?  Sounds like a good start.

Comment: Next thing I would try is add a series resistance term to your fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to skip curve fitting all together by examining the vendor's SPICE model for this device:

```
**********************************
* Copyright:                     *
*   Thomatronik GmbH, Germany    *
*   info@thomatronik.de          *
**********************************
*   SPICE3
.subckt ssa34 1 2
ddio 1 2 legd
dgr 1 2 grd
.model legd d is = 1.73647E-006 n = 1.01682 rs = 0.0395584
+ eg = 0.4 xti = 0.200031 tnom = 27
+ cjo = 8.10972E-010 vj = 0.700021 m = 0.588084 fc = 0.5
+ tt = 1.4427E-009 bv = 44 ibv = 1 af = 1 kf = 0
.model grd d is = 6.76885E-008 n = 0.972506 rs = 0.0698092
+ eg = 1 xti = 0.2 tnom = 27
.ends
```

From the `is` and `n` terms of the `legd` model, you can get the dc behavior as

\$I(V) = I_s(\exp(\frac{V}{nV_t})-1)\$

The `rs` terms shows about 40 mOhms of series resistance, which might explain why your pure logarithmic fit is not perfect at high currents.

You can invert the diode equation and add the series resistance term to get the solution you want:

\$V(I) = nV_t\ln(I/I_s + 1) + IR_s\$

Hopefully this will match (nearly) the curve you have been trying to fit.

Also notice that they had to model the device as two parallel diodes (I am guessing one is a parasitic path and only has a small effect on the overall behavior), so it may not be possible to get a perfect fit to a single exponential curve over a wide current range for this device, even with the series resistance term.

From some spot calculations, the `dgr` diode contributes about 5%-6% of current at reasonable operating points (0.1 - 1 A). You can probably ignore it, because this level of error will probably be lower than your error for not knowing the operating temperature of the diode.

Comment: That's a great idea! I didn't think to look at the model. Vt being equal to 25.85mV at room temperature?

Comment: Shouldn't that be Vf=nVt ln(**I/Is + 1**)? Not (I+Is)?

Comment: Right on both counts. I should have caught it when I was trying to take log of something that isn't unitless.